# Are there sync(ing) programs available that can sync my newer files to the older files?

Tags: software-recommendation, sync

I have two identical linux distrbiutions installed ;  one on the hard disk, and one on the usb.

I was wondering if there is a way of syncing the whole file system, copying the newer files to the old ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to sync just your home directory, that's not too hard.  You could use rsync. Assuming you're booted to the hard drive and you've mounted the USB drive and they are set up identically,

```
 rsync -a --delete ~/ /media/whatever-the-usb-drive-is-called/home/user
```

in a terminal should sync the home directory on the USB version with the version on the hard drive you booted. the `--delete` option means that anything on the USB home that is not on the hard drive home will be deleted. Open a terminal and type

```
 man rsync
```

to read the manual for rsync.

If rsync is not installed on your system,

```
apt-get install rsync
```

will install it.